# Django Model objects not displaying in my template

Tags: django

**I am new to Django. I have problem in displaying model objects into my template**

here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.username
```

here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Employee

@login_required
def home(request):
    context ={
         'employee': Employee.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'newusers/home.html', context)
```

here is my template code:

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="card">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ employee.username }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ employee.email }}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: In this case `employee` will not be a `Employee` instance but rather a `list` object that happens to contain `Employee` instance. A `list` object will have no `username` or `email`  attribute since it's a list and not a `Employee`

Answer (score 0):

You get two distinct notions mixed up: [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/)  and [model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/).

`Employee.objects.all()`, that is to say currently `employee` in your template, is a queryset.

Depending on what you exactly want to achieve, you need to iterate this queryset to access each instance attributes:

```py
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Employee

@login_required
def home(request):
    context ={'employees': Employee.objects.all()}  # note the s at the end
    # here you may want to print `list(context["employees"])` to understand the queryset structure
    return render(request, 'newusers/home.html', context)
```

And then for each `employee` of the queryset `employees`:

```html
{% block content %}
{% for employee in employees %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="card">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ employee.username }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ employee.email }}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```